# LinkedIn Rich Media Shares media

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, linkedin-api

I have Created linkedin app from here "https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps" with use scope of `r_liteprofile`, `r_emailaddress`, `w_member_social`

After connected app successfully auth process I got access token from linkedin api and it's working to get authenticated user information.

But while i try to use Rich Media Shares API then it's not working for me I am getting the following error

> { "serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Not enough permissions to access
>   media resource","status":403 }

Comment: Are you trying to create on a personal profile on an companypage? Please double-check the [permission schema section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/rich-media-shares#permissions)

Comment: Personal profile